# Why is GitLab API sending 404 - File Not Found when called from Java/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab

I am attempting to get the contents of a file within a GitLab repository from a local running Java / Spring Boot application.  Following the GitLab documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository), I have come up with the correct URL string and generated a working PAT.  **The call works without issue when sent from Postman or as a curl from GitBash**.

Here is the pertinent Java class calling GitLab API:

```
package com.dummy.package;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.client.UnknownHttpStatusCodeException;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class GitLabConnector {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    public String getContents() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "glpat-XXX");
        HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        
        String url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id>/repository/files/path%2Fto%2Ffile.txt/raw?ref=main";
        
        try {
            return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class).getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException | UnknownHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            log.error("Error calling GitLab - {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

The response back is `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: "{"message":"404 File Not Found"}"`

When I change the file name to something that truely does not exist, the response back is the same `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: "{"message":"404 File Not Found"}"`

When I change the PAT to an incorrect value, the response back is `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: "{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}"`

When I drop off VPN (it is required in my corporation), the response back is `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: "{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}"`
Notice the change to "Project Not Found" from "File Not Found".

I have submitted the request to a Postman mock server and confirmed that the `PRIVATE-TOKEN` header is included.  I have tried adding all the hidden postman headers into the Java call, but there is no change in response.

---Edit--

I have added a public GitLab repo that reproduces this error.  You can find it here: https://gitlab.com/testing739/sample-project.

The related curl statement is:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/36325066/repository/files/src%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fdata.txt/raw?ref=main' \
--header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-XXX'
```

Comment: I saw a post from a while back where someone replace the ```.txt``` with ```%2e``` in the filename path, but that did not change the response for me.